# TFS VS2010 build agent licensing

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, licensing, continuous-integration

I am just wondering if anyone can give a concrete answer to this question.

We have just installed TFS to a dev server, and to build our web projects properly, we need to install a copy of VS2010 on there also (as stated by MS).

Does anyone know if the MSDN licenses will cover it, as it's not a "production" machine?

Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing or legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274963/questions-about-licensing/274964#274964) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139804/can-licensing-questions-ever-be-on-topic) for details, and the [help] for more.

Comment: Sure - Go for it - also voted to help this along

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [VS 2010 licensing white paper](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13350) has a section for Team Foundation Build scenarios.  As I read it, the developer defining the build needs to have the appropriate VS license, but that's it.  No additional VS license should be needed for the build machine.

Comment: Thanks for this - I don't suppose you could provide the pages you read this? From reading it, it looks like p36?

Comment: I took this to our Tech Services team, and they were happy with it.

Comment: The current version, VS 2013 and MSDN licencing white paper has the following paragraph on page 26... Using Visual Studio on the Build Server
If you have one or more licensed users of Visual Studio Ultimate with MSDN, Visual Studio Premium with MSDN, or Visual Studio Professional with MSDN, then you may also install the Visual Studio software as part of Team Foundation Server 2013 Build Services. This way, you do not need to purchase a Visual Studio license to cover the running of Visual Studio on the build server for each person whose actions initiate a build.